# What happens if multiple put operations are performed on linkedhashmap in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, hashmap, synchronization

I have sample code:

```
Map<Integer, String> hs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
IntStream.range(0,1000).parallel().forEach(value -> hs.put(value, "value"));
System.out.println(hs.size());
```

This is never returning size as 1000 as I understand linkedhashmap is not thread safe and when I use `Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<>());` the size is always 1000 as it is thread safe.

I want to understand what happens in the case of linkedhashmap put operation when multiple threads try to put data in it? How does it have less entries?

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself how a **linked** hashmap works.

As the name implies: by "linking" objects into some sort of "chain", with a data structure that keeps track of the "next" element.

Now imagine the chain ends in object X, and 2 different threads come in and add a new entry that should go after X. Both these threads update that data structure, and the second one overwrites what the first thread did.

In other words: two new elements should be added as HashMap key, but only one of the two actually makes it, the other one is simply lost.

It is like two people throwing bricks into a garbage bin. If they don't pay attention, they might throw bricks at the same time, the bricks "collide", and not both of them end up in the garbage bin.

Comment: What about the case with Hashmap? In case if all the keys end up in different bucket then what will happen with multiple threads?

Comment: @RohitSingh There is still a single data structure keeping track of the different buckets. So you are still open for race conditions. In the end, the real answer is: study the source code. Or implement a simplified version of such collection classes yourself. Then start experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

```java
    hs.put(0, "0");
    hs.put(1, "1");
    hs.put(2, "2");
    // hs should be "0 -> 1 -> 2"
```

```java
    hs.put(0, "0");
    hs.put(1, "1");
    // so sometimes it should be `0.next = 1`
    // because it is not thread safe
    // `2` should be behind 1, but it cut the queue
    // become 0.next = 1; 0.next = 2; `0.next` is assigned twice
    // so the `1` is lost!
    hs.put(2, "2");

    // hs will be "0 -> 2"
```

Comment: What will happen in case of hashmap when multiple threads try to put data and each of them fall into different buckets? Does it still cause the issue?